# Django RequestContext not available

Tags: python, django, request, requestcontext

I can't get RequestContext to work:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/Admin/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/Admin/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/simple.py" in direct_to_template
  26.     c = RequestContext(request, dictionary)
File "/Users/Admin/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in __init__
  176.             self.update(processor(request))

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: 'module' object is not callable
```

I added it to my template context processors:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

What else could I be missing?

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: apparently you have the error elsewhere in the code. Is that the entire stacktrace ? One thing I would do is, go through INSTALLED)APPS one by one and figure out which app is causing the error ?

Comment: Yes that is the entire traceback.. Wow dont even know how to approach this one, sadly..

Comment: you are using a builtin or an imported module name as the view name, or seomthing like that. It would be impossible to "guess" what that is

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion. But what does that mean exactly? You mean that my view name is the same as a module name? Thanks for your ideas

Comment: Yeah. It may be the view name, but not limited to views, but any methods (helper methods, etc...)

Comment: Oh wait. Removing `django.contrib.staticfiles` solves the problem. Any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: Well, it could be some conflicting imports. Sorry I would not be able to exactly tell you why this is happening

Comment: @karthikr adn @Nick-B I was in the same error. My situation was that I tried install `django-suit` and this package did require that I add `'django.template.context_processors'` but for Django 1.9.5 is not necessary. I remove `'django.template.context_processors'` and all works fine.